# Adjuntar codigo Node.Js a un JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, json, nodejs, express

Tengo que realizar una consulta en la base de datos, para luego tomar esos datos y hacer un grafico, el caso es que intento enviar los datos, pero nunca se me muestran del lado del cliente.
Este es el codigo que he escrito en NODE.JS
Estoy utilizando SQL SERVER como motor de base de datos.

```
    (async function () { 
            let pool = await sql.connect(database)
            let result = await pool.request().query('select notas from Notas where status = 1');
            result= console.dir(JSON.stringify(result));
            res.render('index.html', { result });
    })()
});
```

Del lado del cliente siempre intento recibir los datos, pero no me llegan, he probado poniendo los datos en un div html, pero realmente lo que quiero es utilizarlos directamente desde JavaScript del lado del servidor.

`console.log(result);` Tambien he puesto      `let result = document.getElementById("nojoas");`

Pero nada de esto resulta, alguna ayuda? POSDATA: tambien lo he  intentado sin JSON.stringify paro me pasa lo mismo.

Comment: res es una propiedad de express para enviar datos al documento, aqui otro ejempo ```routes.get('/configuracion', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('htdocs/configurations.html');
});
```

Comment: En esta línea: `result= console.dir(JSON.stringify(result));` está el problema. La función`console.dir()` devuelve `undefined`. Quita es método del medio, debes hacerlo así: `result = JSON.stringify(result);`. Comenta cómo te fue con el cambio. Por cierto, no sé porqué quieres convertir el resultado en `string`. Ojo con eso. Saludos